# linq sum how to display as currency

Tags: c#, linq, razor

I have the following in a razor view:

```
<td>@payments.Sum(p => p.Amount)</td>
```

I want it to display as a currency so have '$' and two decimals on the end.

I think normally you go something like {0:C}.

I don't know how to incorporate this into what I've got as the Sum does not have an overload for format.

Do I need to do this with a css class?

Comment: I think you need to go with the `ToString`.  It's a question of value vs. format -- for format, it's the representation of that value and you need to call `ToString` (or some other format method).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would do this:

```
<td>@String.Format("{0:C}", payments.Sum(p => p.Amount))</td>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<td>@payments.Sum(p => p.Amount).ToString("C")</td>
```

I think this is a slightly more efficient call than `String.Format`.  See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10400242/237808).

Comment: Interesting link on `ToString()` vs `String.Format`. For consistency, I tend to use `String.Format` in cases like this because it handles `null` references where `ToString()` would choke. In this case it doesn't matter since `Sum()` will always return an integer value and never be `null`.

Comment: @Yuck . Thanks.  I remember attending an event years ago where the speaker compared `ToString` with `Format` and I was impressed (and a little surprised) by the results.  I tend to favor `ToString` with a formatter string, but it really is a micro-optimization.  Unless it's millions of iterations, either option is fine.