# DateTime?.ToString(format)

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, nullable, datetime-format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I format a nullable DateTime with ToString()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833054/how-can-i-format-a-nullable-datetime-with-tostring)

got issue parsing DateTime? to specific format.
Like:

```
 DateTime t1 = ...;
 string st1 = t1.ToString(format); //<-- works

 DateTime? t1 = ...;
 string st1 = t1.ToString(format); //Dont work.
```

Theres no overload method for DateTime?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
if (t1.HasValue)
    string st1 = t1.Value.ToString(format);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833054/how-can-i-format-a-nullable-datetime-with-tostring

My Bad. Close/delete, please.
Sorry

Answer (score 3):

Use Coalesce Operator

```
DateTime? t1 = ...;

string st1 = t1 ?? t1.Value.ToString(format);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this , nullabale type has the property called hasValue  [Nullable has Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094.aspx)

```
if (t1.HasValue)
   t1.Value.ToString(yourFormat)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check first whether DateTime is null or not

```
 string strDate = (st1 != null ? st1.Value.ToString(format) : "n/a");
```